# Is all raw product always moved to an industry building?

Tags: tropico-3

In Tropico, let's say I have a number of tobacco farms, happily exporting tobacco. Then I build a cigar factory. At this point my teamsters start moving tobacco to the cigar factory, instead of the dock.

However let's say I have more tobacco farms than my cigar factory can possibly process. Will the teamsters keep moving all tobacco to the cigar factory, letting it pile up? Is there a point at which they will start moving some directly to the dock?

I'm playing Tropico 3, but I'm guessing the result will be similar for all the Tropicos. And I'm really asking about all industries, not just tobacco.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All factories have an "input storage" for storing the raw ingredients used in production.  There's a maximum amount that can be stored here, however.  Once all the input storage capacity of your factories is used up, teamsters will take the raw materials to your dock for export instead of taking them to your factories.

You can think of the "no factories" case as being a simple application of this rule - there's essentially 0 input storage maximum on your island at this case, so all raw materials go to the docks.

You can test this by firing most of the workers in the factory and blocking their slots.  This will cause the factory's production to decline, which will cause the input storage amount to increase.  Assuming your raw material production now outstrips the factory's demand, you should notice exports of the raw material.

Further, noticing exports of the raw material is a good indicator that your factory production is in need of optimization or expansion.